# Element not assigned to variable with getElementById, but with querySelector

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

My problem is that when I first tried to assign the element to the variable with getElementById it ended up undefined. When I use querySelevtor instead it works perfectly, but I have no idea why. An explanation or a correction would be much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: " Century Gothic ", Arial , sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            p {
                background-color: #f05a3f;
                padding: 20px;
            }
            p:hover {
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="avsnitt"> Press me! Please! </p>

        <script>
            "use strict"
            //const avsnittEL = document.getElementById('avsnitt')
            const avsnittEl = document.querySelector("#avsnitt")
            avsnittEl.addEventListener('click', nytekst)

            function nytekst() {
                avsnittEl.innerHTML = 'Success!'
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's just a typo in your variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be working fine, notice one thing I did have to change was the `avsnittEl` in the one that uses querySelector and `avsnittEL` in the one that uses getElementById. What I'm talking about specifically here is the capital E lowercase l and the capital E capital L. I believe that was your issue.

```js
"use strict"
const avsnittEL = document.getElementById('avsnitt')
//const avsnittEl = document.querySelector("#avsnitt")
avsnittEL.addEventListener('click', nytekst)

function nytekst() {
  avsnittEL.innerHTML = 'Success!'
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: " Century Gothic ", Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    p {
      background-color: #f05a3f;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    
    p:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="avsnitt"> Press me! Please! </p>

</body>

</html>
```

I left out one crucial part which is the actual explanation between `getElementById` and `querySelector`. The `getElementById` can be used to pull elements from the Document Object Model (DOM) using their Id assigned. The `querySelector` is more of a broad tool that can be used to select many different types of elements from the DOM. For example, the `querySelector` could be used to obtain an element by Id as you've already seen but it could be used to grab an element by class. The `querySelector` will grab the first element that satisfies the query as opposed to `querySelectorAll` which will grab all of them.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, feel silly for being so blind, could have sworn they had the same name.